# Issue with Building Bundle APK in Android Studio: Option Grayed Out

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 17.0.7 on Windows 10, recently updated from an older version. I've encountered an issue where the 'Build Bundle APK' option in the 'Build' menu is grayed out. This prevents me from creating a bundle for my application, which normally should be an available option.

Prior to this, I have tried invalidating the cache and restarting Android Studio, and ensured all components and plugins are up-to-date. However, the option remains inaccessible.

Could anyone provide insights into why this might be happening and suggest potential solutions to enable the 'Build Bundle APK' option?

[image]

Comment: I' dont know what causes it but there are two other options. 
1. Open only the android part of your flutter project in Android Studio and Build/Build Bundle APK button will work.
2. You can build APK/Bundle from cli. I always use this option and if you need help, feel free to ask me and I share more details about it.